# Isotropic subspace of $x_1^2-x_2^2+x_3^2$

Tags: inner-products, quadratic-forms

I have the quadric form $$q(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = x_1^2-x_2^2+x_3^2$$ on a 4-dimensional real vector space $V$, and I was asked to find a 3-dimensional isotropic subspace for that quadratic form.

I think it cannot exist and I tried to give a dimensional proof:

If such isotropic subspace $W$ exists, then $W\subset W^\bot$, so $\dim(W^\bot)\ge\dim(W)$. But then I would have $$4=\dim(V)=\dim(W)+\dim(W^\bot)\ge3+3$$ and this is a contraddiction.

However since the quadratic form is a degenerate form, I think that the equality $$\dim(V)=\dim(W)+\dim(W^\bot)$$ does not hold.

Any hint?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right definitions? Usually "isotropic subspace" is defined to mean the subspace contains at least one isotropic vector. If $W \subseteq W^\perp$ then $W$ would be called *totally* isotropic. In any case, you are right about your proof being wrong; $$\dim V = \dim W + \dim W^\perp$$ need not be true for isotropic $W$ and is false for totally isotropic $W$. In general we have $\leq$ instead of $=$.

Comment: Yes, with isotropic subspace I mean totally isotropic. Is there some result to estimate the dimension of $W^\bot$ in this case?

Comment: In general, no, it can be anything between $\dim V - \dim W$ and $\dim V$. This is how I would approach the problem: Let $V_3$ be the subspace spanned by $$(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)$$ and note that $$V^\perp = (0,0,0,1)\mathbb R.$$ If we're looking for a totally isotropic 3D subspace, then this has to be $V_3$ or a $S\oplus V^\perp$ where $S \subseteq V_3$ is a totally isotropic plane. It is not $V_3$ because the form is nontrivial on $V_3$, so we need to look for $S$. Now examine the isotropic vectors of $V_3$ to see why there is no such $S$.

Comment: "If we're looking for a totally isotropic 3D subspace, then this has to be $V_3$
 or a $S\oplus V^\bot$
 where $S\subset V_3$
 is a totally isotropic plane." I didn't get this part. Why I have only these two alernatives?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment. This is a bit too long to itself be a comment.

I was a little sloppy in what I said; it's not that $S$ can only be in $V_3$, it's just that that is the only case that matters.

All isotropic vectors are of the form $v_3 + v_0$ where $v_3 \in V_3$ is isotropic and $v_0 \in V^\perp$. Looking for non-degenerate isotropic vectors means looking for isotropic vectors of $V_3$.

If $S$ contains some $v_0$ then it is spanned by $v_3, v_0$. Completing $S$ to an isotropic 3-space requires another isotropic $v_3'$ orthogonal to $v_3$, so $v_3, v_3'$ span a totally isotropic plane in $V_3$.

If $S$ does not contain some $v_0$, then it is spanned by $v_3+v_0$ and $v_3'+\alpha v_0$ for some $\alpha$. If $v_3, v_3'$ are orthogonal then they span a totally isotropic plane in $V_3$, so assume otherwise. Clearly $w = v_3'-\alpha v_3 \in V_3\cap S$. The map $L(x) = x + \beta\langle x, w\rangle v_0$ fixes $w$ and $v_0$ and is an invertible linear isometry for each scalar $\beta \not= 0$. We can choose $\beta$ so that $L(v_3 + v_0) = v_3$, so the image of $S$ under $L$ is a totally isotropic plane in $V_3$.

Comment: So you are using a sort of "Witt Theory", aren't you?

Comment: @aleio1 I'm not sure what you mean, but [Witt's cancellation theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt's_theorem#Witt's_cancellation_theorem) is relevant to my argument and I could clean up the last paragraph by invoking that explicitly.